# TeraTerm Invalid Host when running .ttl file

Tags: teraterm

Running on a new Windows install. I installed tera Term and copied over a .ttl file I used on a previous windows version. When I try to launch the macro I get an `Invalid Host` pop-up error.

I can open Tera Term as normal and connect to the host defined in my .ttl file without any problems, it's only when I try to run my script.

I've tested this on both Tera Term `Version 4.78` as well as `Version 4.105`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing around I managed to solve this problem, giving it a real answer so that hopefully if someone else has this problem they will find this.

The problem was that by default my `.ttl` files were set to open with `Tera Term` I instead had to set it to open with `Tera Term Macro Interpreter`, which is an executable that lives in your `Tera Term` install directory.